# CSS3 Horizontal div alignment

Tags: css, html, alignment

So what I'm trying to do is

```
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
|-------|leftdiv-250px|centerdiv-1000px|rightdiv-250px|-------|
|-------------------------------------------------------------|
```

So here's the HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="header-top">
        <div id="header-top-main">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="header-main">
        <div id="header-main-inner">
            <div id="header-main-left">
            </div>
            <div id="header-main-center">
            </div>
            <div id="header-main-right">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS

```
#header {
    height: 190px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #e5e5e5;
    margin: auto;
}

#header-top {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #e9e9e9;
    background-image: url(../img/header-top-bg.png);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 10px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 999;
    position: relative;

}

#header-top-main {
    height: 50px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}

#header-main {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

#header-main-inner {
    margin: auto;
    width: auto;
}

#header-main-left {
    width: 250px;
    height: 140px;
    background: url(../img/header-main-left-bg.png);
    float: left;
}

#header-main-center {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 140px;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    display: inline;

}

#header-main-right {
    width: 250px;
    height: 140px;
    background: url(../img/header-main-right-bg.png);
    float: right;

}
```

So I'm not sure what the problem is, I've tried to float them all left in a wrapper that has an auto margin but hadn't seemed to work. Another issue that came up was it all displayed in 1 line, but it stacks up on the left of the page, continuing all the way to right, giving the page a scroll.

What I want is, for the 'header-main' area to be centered with the 3 divs. And if the 'header-main' area goes off page, I would want it to continue off page without a scroll. If a screenshot of what I'm trying to do is needed, then I can provide it.

here would be another example

```
--------------------|------[        header-top          ]------|-------------------
space beyond screen |------[leftdiv][centerdiv][rightdiv]------| spce beyond screen
--------------------|------[        navigation          ]------|-------------------
```

Comment: can you create a Fiddle please?

Comment: I am by no means a frequent visitor to SO. But even I have seen this very question posted at least 10 times. You may find the links on the right of this page helpful.

Comment: @Scott I hadn't had much success seeing other peoples issues, had been looking around for a while.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aLLya/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add floats to the elements, height to the elements, and a min-width to the parent.

```
#header-main-left,
#header-main-center,
#header-main-right {
    float: left;
    height: 140px;
}
#header-main-inner {
    min-width: 1500px;
}
```

And then to stop the scrolling, I would say to add an `overflow: hidden;`:

```
#header-main {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DuqEj/1/)

Comment: I've tried to use overflow: hidden; but I haven't had any success with that. Will let you know how it works out.

Comment: If you want that then put `#header { overflow: hidden; }`.

Comment: Tried that, and had some success. However the rightdiv is appearing off page.

Comment: You simply can't put 1500px width on screen that is 1000px, right div must go off.

Comment: @mdesdev thus the overflow

Comment: Of course but if you dont hide overflow it's gonna scroll, if you hide it then the right div must go off screen. Can't have both. In my fiddle I set inner elements to width in %, that way all divs stay on screen, but of course size changes according to screen width.

Comment: Would using one div, center alined `margin: auto;` with `1500px` width and `overflow: hidden;` be a workaround to this?

Comment: @Peter so you want it centered no matter what you mean?

Comment: Yes, I want it centered no matter the screen resolution. even if the leftdiv and rightdiv go off page, but keeping the main wrapper centered.

Comment: Ah, then that will be absolute positioning. `left: 50%; margin-left: -750px;`

Answer (score 1):

This will fix your problem with div positioning, here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/CHhyE/)

```
#header-main-left,
#header-main-center,
#header-main-right {
  float: left;
  height: 140px;
}

#header-main-left {
  width: 25%;
  background: url(../img/header-main-left-bg.png);
}

#header-main-center {
  width: 50%;
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

#header-main-right {
  width: 25%;
  background: url(../img/header-main-right-bg.png);
}
```

Second part I don't understand well

"And if the 'header-main' area goes off page, I would want it to continue off page without a scroll."

Comment: By that I mean, the whole 'header-main' div stays stationary in the center, and for example if the screen is to small, it wouldn't affect the 1000px / 1500px layout and there would be no horizontal scroll

Comment: In Fiddle I remove horizontal scroll with `body { overflow-x: hidden; }` but if your `header-main` is `1500px` horizontal scroll would appear on smaller screens except if you set `body { overflow-x: hidden; }`.